# How to use a digital RGB LED Strip?

Tags: led, digital, rgb-led

I know this is probably a little bit basic but I need SERIOUS help with using my new led strip. You can see here the type of strip I have, and the packet.

[image]
[image]
[image]

It's difficult because it looks slightly different to all the other ones I've seen in tutorials so I don't really know where to start now...All I've done is cut off the ends of the wires already on there and replace them with the regular pins that I can use on the Arduino and breadboards too. Where do I have to go from here? Are there any code libraries I need to use?

Comment: My bet would be that these are WS2812B LED strips. They should be compatible with Adafruit Neopixels.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the DAT (Green wire) is a digital data wire. Try the following:
1. VCC to +5V pin
2. GND to GND pin
3. DAT to 2 Digital pin.

Then try to change the state of the 2 digital pin from high to low and see if anything happens... That's what I would start out with.

Comment: Interesting result, about 3 of the lights came on, and were all different colors, then I adjusted the wires and they went off, and still are off...

Comment: Worst case scenario- the board did not have resistors and you just burned them down. Do you have schematic of your led strip?

Comment: No I don't think so, I could find some but who knows if it would be the right one. Would a close up photo do?

Comment: I added one anyway, there is a tiny piece in the centre wire or the strip right next to the LED, is that a resistor?

Comment: If by that you mean the element that has letter C near it, it should be capacitor because C stands for capacitance. But it also could be resistor because they look pretty much the same. Try to find a schematic, it's pretty hard to help when I don't even know what's on the board.

Comment: @L2PA these LED strips have "constant current" drivers built in. My bet would be them being these `https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812B.pdf` or `https://www.adafruit.com/images/product-files/1138/SK6812%20LED%20datasheet%20.pdf`

Comment: @L2PA Plus, they are "Digital LED strips" so changing the state of digital pin 2 isn't going to do a lot, unless you time it exactly right. I also wouldn't recommend driving an analog LED strip directly from Arduino..

Comment: Ok, I think I found them on aliexpress, they look exactly the same as mine so I'll try look for the schematics now, heres the link if you want to take a look, not sure if theres anything useful...http://www.aliexpress.com/item/1M-WS2812B-Full-Color-LED-strip-light-Built-in-WS2811-30-LED-30-pixels-Raspberry-Pi/32601142057.html?spm=2114.01010208.3.112.jf2vIu&ws_ab_test=searchweb201556_6,searchweb201602_3_10017_10005_10006_10034_10021_507_10022_508_10020_9912_10018_10019,searchweb201603_7&btsid=c6194586-8b45-4a24-ac33-795408b73bc3

Comment: Right, I found it, @Paul you were right, it was these: https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812B.pdf

Comment: You're somewhat in luck, Adafruit has an "Neopixel uberguide" which is an extensive document on how to use these type of strips. They also have a library which should make programming easier.

Comment: @Paul Is this it? https://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide.pdf

Comment: All working now, thanks @paul for that uberguide!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, in every example you see wiring diagrams with 3 wires, and my ledstrip had 5 wires, but it seems the two red wires (5v) are connected and the two white wires (gnd) are connected to eachother, so basicly you have 3 wires like in every wiring diagrams  what's out there